# HTML form action doesn't redirect

Tags: php, html

I am very confused that my html form action doesn't redirect me to another page, because this has always worked.

Here's my code

```
 <section class="contact section-padding" data-scroll-index="6">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="section-head text-center col-sm-12">
                    <h4>Neem contact op</h4>
                    <h6>Vul formulier in</h6>
                </div>

                <div class="offset-lg-2 col-lg-8 offset-md-1 col-md-10">
                    <form method="post" class="form" id="contact-form" action="verstuurd.php">

                        <div class="messages"></div>

                        <div class="controls">

                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input id="form_name" type="text" name="volledige_naam" placeholder="Volledige naam">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mailadres" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input id="form_subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Onderwerp">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <textarea id="form_message" name="message" placeholder="Bericht" rows="4" ></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                    <button type="submit"><span>Verstuur</span></button>
                                </div>

                            </div>                             
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

What is wrong with this? I thought it might has to do something with the div classes, but is this possible?

**Edit**

*Verstuurd.php*

```
<section class="contact section-padding" data-scroll-index="6">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="section-head text-center col-sm-12">
                    <h4>Succesvol verstuurd</h4>
                    <h6>We nemen zo snel mogelijk contact met u op</h6>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

At the moment I do not have any php code in *verstuurd.php*. I thought that `aciton` only redirects to PHP files and not HTML files.

Comment: Can we see the PHP code for `verstuurd.php`, as that is most likely where your issue is.

Comment: @ScottieG Done.

Comment: Your PHP file contains no PHP?

Comment: _“I thought that aciton only redirects to PHP files and not HTML files.”_ - well, you simply thought wrong here. (And in more way than one, because you are dealing with _URLs_ here, not _files_. URLs _can_ be based on the file system structure, but they don’t have to be.)

Comment: What _does_ happen when you click the "Verstuur" button?

Comment: @04FS Ok, but it doesn't matter that it is a PHP file right?

Comment: @SamTolton Nothing happens

Comment: @j08691 True, but changing it to HTML also does not work.

Comment: @Jip1912 that's odd because I have replicated your code locally and it works fine.

Comment: @SamTolton so that means it has to do something with my css?

Comment: I'm guessing there's some javascript that is blocking the form submission. Look out for anything similar to `e.preventDefault();` in relation to form submission.

Comment: @SamTolton I removed every `e.preventDefault();` from the javascripts just to check it, but it still does not work.

Comment: @Jip1912 I would remove all javascript completely and check again. I don't believe CSS can prevent forms from being submitted, so it must be in the javascript.

Comment: @SamTolton still no change. The code is in an iframe though, but that doesn't matter right?

Comment: @Jip1912 yes it's possible the iframe can have an effect on the form inside it. For example you could set the `sandbox` attribute on the iframe to prevent forms inside the iframe from being submitted.

Comment: It must be something like that as the code works on its own as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/uherjxmk/  When you submit the form it tried to go to `verstuurd.php` but that doesn't exists in this example so you get a 404.

Comment: @SamTolton I found out that my local server didn't refresh the files correctly. When I change text, it immediately changes, but when I for example change the javascript files it does not. The problem was `e.preventDefault();` I think. It works now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing there's some javascript that is blocking the form submission. Look out for anything similar to `e.preventDefault();` in relation to form submission.

Comment: It works when I open the html file locally, but when I open it with XAMPP or USB Webserver, it doesn't do anything when I submit. Why is that?

Answer (score -2):

Change your button from

```
 <button type="submit"><span>Verstuur</span></button>
```

to

```
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Verstuur">
```